# MapKit: highlighting an annotation view

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have a map view with some annotations on it. I use a custom pin image for the annotations.

I am transitioning away from showing callouts to having a table view slide up from the bottom to show information about the annotation that was touched. As-is there is no way to see on the map which annotation is selected.

What I would like is to have the annotation to animate to a highlighted appearance when it is selected, and animate to a regular appearance when it's deselected, much like a system style UIButton in the selected state. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to just switch between different image files when the user taps on the annotation. I don't think you'll need to animate it - it looks fine without animation in our app.

If the user taps on an item in the tableView, you'll want to switch to the highlighted image and probably center the map at that point as well.

The only problem we've had is trying to keep the highlighted annotation view in front of other overlapping annotation views. Annotation view z-order is, as far as I know, not something that can be consistently and easily controlled.

Comment: I have had good results with annotationView.layer.zPosition. I just set it to 2 in the selection callback and set it back to 1 in the deselection callback. I thought I mentioned about changing the image. I just found the transition to the highlighted state abrupt. I was hoping there was some animation technique that would enable a good-looking transition.

Comment: I got good results with a "highlighted" image that simply lights the pin up like a lightbulb. Thanks for the suggestion.